# GaN Power transitor said to "reduce EMI"

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, emi-filtering, gan

I have no experience in GaN, I am currently discovering the subject and I was studying a design from Infineon and I found on a GaN power transistor the following benefits:

[image]

Here is the datasheet: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IGT60R070D1-DataSheet-v02_14-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265f064ff016686028dd56526

That is not really intuitive to me to reduce EMI when you increase the switching frequency. So what does it mean?

Have a nice day : )

Comment: Page 1 of the data sheet is owned by marketing people and they will stretch the truth however, I have heard that using that MOSFET increases your manhood.

Comment: Well, "No reverse recovery charge" would eliminate one of the common sources of switching noise spikes (related to the body diode in most FETs) when the FET is turned off. So, that would be my guess. However, "low gate charge" implies lower gate drive current spikes too (though 5 nC doesn't look all that low to me)

Comment: @user_1818839 You re right ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switching frequency is not decisive here.

The main EMI problems occur from high frequency ringing around the switch, which is triggered by the switch turning on/off.

The main problems of conventional MOSFETs is the large gate capacitance (requiring a lot of gate current, i.e. high dI/dt), the large package inductance (due to large physical size), and reverse recovery ringing.

WBG FETs improve all of these metrics. The physical size improvement is only in part warranted by the material though. In part, it is just a modern design decision and Si parts with very flat packages also benefit greatly from this.